# object properties as key value pairs in hash function

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, hash, hashtable

I have a basic question regard to Javascript.

as Javascript do not have hash table objects, but I realize that I can just build a object to use it as a hash table like the following:

```
var hashtable = {
    Today : {"I", "feel", "good"},
    Tomorrow : {'is', 'another', 'day'},
    Yesterday : 'alwaysGood'
}
```

I have search a lot on the Internet, there are some means which using associativeArray or which build its own object as a hash table, is the above native object building method not good？

Comment: Well you cannot do exactly what you've posted, as it's syntactically incorrect. However the basic idea of using an object like a hash table is fine.

Comment: ^^ What he said, the idea is fine, but your code is invalid, and there are no associative arrays in javascript.

Comment: @adeneo Objects *are* [associative arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array)

Comment: @AndrewVermie Technically, no, they're not -- but they can be used like associative arrays in other languages are used.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between objects and associated array in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146104/whats-the-difference-between-objects-and-associated-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code sample is not valid JavaScript because of this `{"I", "feel", "good"}`. In this context, the curly braces represent an object literal, and each of the object's properties must be assigned a value.

A valid version would look like:

```
var hashtable = {
    Today : ["I", "feel", "good"],
    Tomorrow : ['is', 'another', 'day'],
    Yesterday : 'alwaysGood'
}
```

Note the use of `[]` which creates an array. Arrays in JavaScript are numerically keyed, there is no concept of an associative array like there is in other languages. However, a JavaScript array itself, is also an object, so you can freely add properties:

```
var arr = [];
arr.Today = 'some value';
```

To avoid the use of an array in your example, you would need to set values for all properties:

```
var hashtable = {
    Today : {"I" : "i val", "feel" : "feel val", "good" : "good val"},
    Tomorrow : {'is' : 'is val', 'another' : 'another val', 'day' : 'day val'},
    Yesterday : 'alwaysGood'
}
```

Using objects in this way is valid and acceptable. For more information refer to [Working With Objects (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).